# Geo Nodes : Randomize object input

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an empty where I would like geo nodes to place a random object at the empty's position from a selection of meshes in a Collection. I'd like just a random exposed Seed to decide which object is placed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Point Instance Node* you have the option to instance a *Collection*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was easy! ;D